# CSS3: "note lines" are jumping when text is long

Tags: css, repeating-linear-gradient

I want to imitate "note lines" using `repeating-linear-gradient` (or simply line `background-image`, not important):

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.box--gradient {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent 25px, #011852 25px, #011852 26px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box box--gradient">
  Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? 
</div>
```

As you can see if text is long, then lines are jumping. I can find such `line-height` and `repeating-linear-gradient` values that all look fine, but if I change browser scale it brokes again.

So how can I calculate right "line" size?

Thank`s a lot!

Codepen:  https://codepen.io/mraimon/pen/REdbOp

Answer (score 3):

The repeating gradient should repeat each `line-height` and not `line-height+1`. You should do something like below instead:

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.box--gradient {
  background-image: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(
    transparent, /*from 0*/
    transparent calc(25px - 1px), #011852 calc(25px - 1px), /*here do what you want*/
    #011852 25px /*to 25px*/
   );
}
```

```html
<div class="box box--gradient">ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp ppp </div>
```

In stylus:

```
$line-height = 25px;

.box {
  width: 500px;
  line-height: $line-height;
}

.box--gradient {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent $line-height - 1px, #011852 $line-height - 1px, #011852 $line-height)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answer, but if I click `ctrl +`, there is the same problem again :c I tried with `em`'s too, but without resul

Comment: @MRaimon are you sure? If I zoom it's fine for me

Comment: I added image to post, this is screenshot of your snippet

Comment: @MRaimon did you clear your cache? the code is updated?

Comment: yes, sure. this code `repeating-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent calc(25px - 1px), #011852 calc(25px - 1px), #011852 25px);` I tried in my codepen - the same problem when I zoom

Comment: @MRaimon which browser?

Comment: Chrome and Safari (last versions)

Comment: @MRaimon hmm .. I am also testing using chrome and it's fine even at 200% zoom

Comment: @MRaimon Ah indeed, if the value are floats, you won't have accurate result, so better avoir them. You can consider em unit by the way.

Comment: yes, I know that foats values are not good in such situations :) and I use only integers.
with `em` the same problem

Comment: @MRaimon well, since I am not able to reproduce your issue, you may ask another quesion where you show the code, the issue and the browser you are using, probably other user you will see the same and you can get some workarounds